# Change a string.xml string in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, string.xml

I want to change the hint property of an `edittext` field from my activity layout in a function I created in mainActivity.kt. The previous value of hint was from `string.xml` in `resources -> values -> string.xml` file.

How do I access `string` in main and change its value to something else?

Comment: AFAIK you cant change the value in strings.xml

Comment: you can get the value as  `getString(R.string.yourString);`

Comment: try myEditText.setHint("NEW HINT");

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. If you have in your `string.xml` value like this

```
<string name="simple_text">Simple text</string>
```

And you want to use the text from your MainActivity, you can write this code

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.simple_text));
```

In you case you can change the hint like this

```
editText.setHint(getString(R.string.simple_text));
```

But you can't from MainActivity change any value in `Strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setHint(getString(R.string.simple_text));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: i know, you don't need to worry about me, do your work don't put you leg between us. ok ??

Comment: Reviewing low quality posts is my work. If you don't want to include an explanation, there's no need to reply to my review.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change strings.xml dynamically since it's a compiled resource. There are other ways for saving data in Android, here's a nice post that covers this topic: [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Hope this helps.
But you can change the hint value dynamically.

```
EditText etUsername;
etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
etUsername.setHint("Your Hint");
```

Comment: This is already answered above.